# Need Mongodb schema validator script for the given schema

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot

Hi all i have been trying out various combination in the last few days to pinpoint how to create schema validator. Meaning a collection wont just take any input but will accept only what is given in the validator.
I created below collection via mongo-repository in spring.
Can you please provide the validator for the same. And also give links which will do complex mongodb collections to java pojo mapping. It would be of great help. All i found was simple validators or java to mongo collection not vice versa

```
    {
  "_id": {
    "$numberInt": "1"
  },
  "listOfItems": [
    {
      "itemid": {
        "$numberInt": "1"
      },
      "qty": {
        "$numberInt": "10"
      },
      "qty_type": "kg",
      "cost": "20",
      "currency": "INR"
    },
    {
      "itemid": {
        "$numberInt": "2"
      },
      "qty": {
        "$numberInt": "10"
      },
      "qty_type": "kg",
      "cost": "20",
      "currency": "INR"
    },
    {
      "itemid": {
        "$numberInt": "3"
      },
      "qty": {
        "$numberInt": "10"
      },
      "qty_type": "kg",
      "cost": "20",
      "currency": "INR"
    }
  ],
  "_class": "com.daily.essential.cartservice.model.Cart"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

//this should answer your question

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const productSchema = mongoose.Schema({

//mongoose generates a new rando unique Id for the product
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
//mongoose makes sure that the name input by the user is a string and mongoose makes the /name field required that means the user must not leave the field empty.
    name: {type: String, required: true},
//mongoose makes sure that the price input by the user is a a Number and mongoose makes //the price field required that means the user must not leave the field empty.
    price: {type: Number, required: true}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);